# How to connect to Play Framework in-memory database using JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, playframework, h2, in-memory-database

I use the in-memory database that comes with Play Framework, when I have `db=mem` in the configuration file, for development.

How can I connect to this database using JDBC? and not the JPA that is the default way.

I have tried with this method in my controller:

```
public static void addToDB() {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:play");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(sql);
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I get an error message that I need to provide an username and password:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [8004-149]
```

If I visit the web-console on `/@db` the username `sa` is used and no password.

---

Now I logged in via the `/@db` interface and created a table `users`.

Then I connected to the database in a controller method and used this jdbc-string: `jdbc:h2:mem:play:sa` and then tried to insert to the table `users` but I get this error message:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement:
```

How should I connect to the in-memory H2 database in Play Framework using JDBC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DB.getConnection()`, should do the job.

Comment: Is a new connection returned every time I call it? or is it the same that I shouldn't close?

Comment: It the connection given from the HibernateSession. So I would assume that it's better you don't close it.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:play", "sa", "");
```

because as you wrote, "the username sa is used and no password."

Comment: +1 I was confusing the URL name with the user name; thanks for clarifying.